# How can I get the typescript version that my LSP server is using?

Tags: typescript, sublimetext, language-server-protocol

How do I get the typescript version that LSP is using to check my code? I'm seeing some bugs in my typescript code that may possibly be version-dependant.

Comment: Which LSP server are you using for Typescript ? Depending on the server used, the available features are not the same.

Comment: The LSP defines the #initializeResult where a server version is set. Perhaps the server version also matches the Typescript version is handling? https://microsoft.github.io/language-server-protocol/specifications/lsp/3.17/specification/#initializeResult